# Split comma separated values in sql based on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Hi all i am newbie in SQL i have a table in which there is a column named dilution_name in this column there are values coming in comma separated format like A,B,C etc. also these values may vary like in some row the values are A,B,C and in some case its like A,B,C,D i just want to separate these values and print them in multiple column if there is only 3 comma separated values then there should be 3 values in comma would be written rest should be null 
I have tried

```
    select ParsedData.* 
    from dilution_table mt
    cross apply ( select str = mt.dilution_name + ',,' ) f1
    cross apply ( select p1 = charindex( ',', str ) ) ap1
    cross apply ( select p2 = charindex( ',', str, p1 + 1 ) ) ap2
    cross apply ( select p3 = charindex( ',', str, p2 + 2 ) ) ap3
    cross apply ( select p4 = charindex( ',', str, p3 + 3 ) ) ap4
    cross apply ( select p5 = charindex( ',', str, p4 + 4 ) ) ap5
    cross apply ( select p6 = charindex( ',', str, p5 + 5 ) ) ap6
    cross apply ( select val1 = substring( str, 1, p1-1 )                   
             , val2 = substring( str, p1+1, p2-p1-1 ),
              val3 = substring( str, p2+1, p2-p1-1 ),
              val4 = substring( str, p3+1, p2-p1-1 ),
              val5 = substring( str, p4+1, p2-p1-1 ),
              val6 = substring( str, p5+1, p2-p1-1 ),
              val7 = substring( str, p6+1, p2-p1-1 )
      ) ParsedData  


            [sample data][1]
```

[sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1eKQ.png)

Comment: For columns, take a peek at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40609102/tsql-parse-string-with-4-delimiters/40609526#40609526

Comment: @vkp  - I agree this is a dupe, but two quick points.  1) OP wanted columns not rows, and 2) At least point to a set-based splitter, not a multi-statement loop.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2016+ you can use `string_split()` (though it has no ordinal number).

In SQL Server pre-2016, using a CSV Splitter table valued function by Jeff Moden:

```
declare @str varchar(128) = 'a,b,c,d'

select s.ItemNumber, s.Item
from dbo.delimitedsplit8k(@str,',') s;
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/EGZ24917

returns:

```
+------------+------+
| ItemNumber | Item |
+------------+------+
|          1 | a    |
|          2 | b    |
|          3 | c    |
|          4 | d    |
+------------+------+
```

---

To pivot the data after splitting, you can use conditional aggregation like so:

```
select 
    v1 = max(case when s.ItemNumber = 1 then s.Item end)
  , v2 = max(case when s.ItemNumber = 2 then s.Item end)
  , v3 = max(case when s.ItemNumber = 3 then s.Item end)
  , v4 = max(case when s.ItemNumber = 4 then s.Item end)
  , v5 = max(case when s.ItemNumber = 5 then s.Item end)
from dbo.delimitedsplit8k(@str,',') s;
```

returns:

```
+----+----+----+----+------+
| v1 | v2 | v3 | v4 |  v5  |
+----+----+----+----+------+
| a  | b  | c  | d  | NULL |
+----+----+----+----+------+
```

---

splitting strings reference:

- [Tally OH! An Improved SQL 8K “CSV Splitter” Function - Jeff Moden](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/)
- [Splitting Strings : A Follow-Up - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-follow-up)
- [Split strings the right way – or the next best way - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)
- [**`string_split()`** in SQL Server 2016 : Follow-Up #1 - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2016/04/sql-server-2016/string-split-follow-up-1)
- [Ordinal workaround for **`string_split()**` - Solomon Rutzky](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback/Details/2433171)

Comment: i did not want split values and print in rows i just want if there are 5 comma separated values then 5 column horizontal be visible and if there are 4 comma separated values then 4 values should be there and 5th column would be null

Comment: @shravanpal My mistake, updated to include conditional aggregation form of pivot after splitting.

Comment: sir i was tied your code but i did not got desire result

Comment: @shravanpal Add example data and desired results to your question

Comment: sir i have solved the problem your couple of codes help me to solve my problem any ways thanks.